# Log4j Version 2.17.2 disable logrotate when editing log4j.xml-files

Tags: java, xml, log4j, logrotate

i have following problem:
Everytime we edit our log4j.xml-configuration-files a logrotate happens.
So we store those logs in our archive and open a new one with starting time at that point, when the logrotate occurs. But when our real logrotate at midnight happens, the already stored file will be overwritten. So we lose that part of our logs.

I think this behaviour when changing the log4j-config files was introduced only a few versions ago but i cannot find out when exactly.

Configuring it with monitorIntervall does also not help, because that would only work if the files are changend at the exact time in seconds.

Do you guys know a method to disable the check when the log4j-files are edited and move on without a logrotate?

Thanks in advance

Here is the configuration:
[log4j-confi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5daLh.png)

Comment: Can you edit you question and add your configuration? Either you have a trigger that rotates upon reconfiguration or there is a bug that should be reported.

Comment: I switched over away from the CronTrigger to a timebasedTriggerPolicy which (up to now ) works. So maybe there was the problem.

Comment: The `evaluateOnStartup="true"` setting has the effect you describe in the question. Please, include your configuration as text not image, so that it can be searchable.